# Measuring a string in PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing, measurement

ASP has a MeasureString function that returns the width, in pixels, of a string given a certain font/size. Is this possible in PHP?

Comment: Keep in mind, the solutions below are estimates, you can't be 100% sure the exact pixel value is correct, it might be off by 5% or so, so factor that into whatever you're doing with the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using GD library.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php

this is for text rendered on an image.
Text width varies a bit depending on the browser, OS (font smoothing, different rendering)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use the [imagettfbbox](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) function if you have GD installed